# In a hadoop environment who creates the data splits in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, split, hdfs, bigdata

I have a big data problem (sorta) that I wish to solve using Hadoop. Simply put, we have a job or a task involves reading a huge file with more than a billion records, parse through the files, line by line, do some cleansing and write the cleansed data to another file. We expect to have hundreds of such jobs that are constantly being created, submitted, ran. Each job deals with its own files, so we don't have to worry about concurrency issues.

I understand from a very high level, how I could use Hadoop to achieve this. But what I fail to grasp is, whose job is it to split this huge file into splits, that are to be stored in the data nodes. Is my understanding below correct?

```
JOB:
Client (has the big input file) ->  
Splits the file into chunks (how do I know split size??) -> 
Asks Name Node where to store data (how will the name node know how\where to allocate?)-> 
Name Node responds with Data Node Information -> 
Client copies (using Hadoop FS) the split data to appropriate DataNodes ->
Client submits Job (gives all the relavant info, map/reduce)->
JobTracker schedules\runs it ->
DataNodes run map\reduce tasks ->
```

ouput files are created in DataNodes
  Merge all the output files for client's consumption (who does this?)

Any help\comment would be appreciated

Thanks
Kay

Comment: Hadoop itself has map/reduce, you can write in different langs, such as Java and Python. Also, you can use Apache Spark.

Comment: How does that answer my question stated above?

Answer (score 0):

there are two types of chunks created in the whole process of data storing and mapreduce. 
1) when you submit a file to client asking him to store it, it breaks the file into blocks (default size is 128 MB in Hadoop v2, 64 MB in Hadoop v1). The client then asks namenode to provide with datanodes on which it has to store the data. The namenode provides these details based on availability of datanodes and network distance from client to datanodes.
2) when you submit a job to be run on that file, the file is divided into logical inputsplits. the number of input splits created is equal to number of mappers. This split size is not fixed. It varies or depends on logic.

From hadoop v2, there is no concept of jobtracker or task tracker. When a client submits job, yarn controls the execution of the job.

```
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/input-splits-in-hadoops-mapreduce.html
```

This can help you understanding what inputsplits are.

Comment: Who is acting as client? It is certainly not the user program, Is it the Hadoop API that the user is talking to referred as client?

Comment: Also how does the client decide how the file is divided into blocks. Lets say I have a 256MB file, which I believe will be split into 2 blocks, what if the data block 1 does not have all the data for my MAP task to work?

Comment: Client is not the user. its one of the resources of cluster. when you type any command to execute on command prompt (like hadoop fs ..), this first 2 words internally calls client and gives the rest of command to it. It furthur takes care of executing them.

Comment: Client decides on splits based on logic provided in RecordReader.         https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/understand-recordreader-inputsplit/       This link will help you in understanding how splits and mappers are linked. https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/custom-recordreader-processing-string-pattern-delimited-records/  This link will help you out in writing your own split.(eg: in a text document  inspite of reading a line at a time, you want to read one paragraph at a time)

Answer (score 0):

When the inputs are files, hadoop normally use **FileInputFormat** class or one of its subclasses. That class has the method **isSplitable** that define if the files is splitable or not. Not all file format allow split the work (for example GZip files are not splitable and even a file has several blocks, all of them require to be processed for the same mapper).

If the file is splitable Hadoop call getSplit method that all **InputFormat** implementations have to implement to get a list of logical splits.